# virtual-dom - how to get hold of real DOM element in order to integrate with spin.js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, spin.js, virtual-dom

When using the [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) library, how can I get hold of the real DOM element corresponding to a virtual one? The use case is I need to manipulate the DOM via the [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) library.

Correspondingly, in React you would call [React.findDOMNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.finddomnode) in order to get hold of the element to pass to spin.js.

Example code:

```
let el = h('#spinner')
# TODO: Pass real DOM element, not virtual, but how?
new Spinner().spin(el)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I could solve this by registering a hook on the virtual node in question, a little documented feature of [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) AFAICT. The hook gets called with the real DOM node once it's rendered.

virtual-dom is very specific about its hooks, they need to be objects with `hook` and `unhook` functions on their prototypes (can't be direct properties).

```
let h = require('mercury').h

// Hook to get hold of real DOM node
let Hook = () => {}
Hook.prototype.hook = (node) => {
  // Do what thou wilst with the node here
}
Hook.prototype.unhook = () => {}

// Mercury component
let Component = () => {
}

Component.render = (state) => {
  // Create virtual node with hook
  return h('div', {
    hook: new Hook(),
  })
}
```